# Add the auth state listener to every component that needs it or can I add it only to the main App component and provide it furtther as a context

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I was wondering which one is a better practice for a React app with firebase, I understand from the firebase docs that I should add it on every page that needs it, bu I was thinking that it would be easier to provide it as a context to all my components since pretty much all of them are relying on the user state to display the right information. So which one is better ?

I have tried both but I do not know which one is better in terms of best practices or when to use each approach .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of these is pertinently better than the other.

The Firebase SDKs cache the auth information already, so adding an auth state listener in each component does not require extra calls to the server.

But there's also nothing wrong in principle with getting the state once at a higher level component and pushing it down into child components that needs it. Just make sure to re-render those child components when the auth state changes.